# mentioning all artifacts in a base pom in maven2

Tags: java, maven-2

is there any way to include all the artifacts present in remote repository in a project's pom file without explicitly mentioning each? I mean i require all the artifacts but for that do i have to mention `<groupId> <artifactId> and <version>` for each separately?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the dependencies and reuse them. [Read this](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html) for details.

> let’s assume that your application uses Hibernate, a popular
>   Object-Relational mapping framework. Every project which uses
>   Hibernate might also have a dependency on the Spring Framework and a
>   MySQL JDBC driver. Instead of having to include these dependencies in
>   every project that uses Hibernate, Spring, and MySQL you could create
>   a special POM that does nothing more than declare a set of common
>   dependencies. You could create a project called persistence-deps
>   (short for Persistence Dependencies), and have every project that
>   needs to do persistence depend on this convenience project: